# "Overflow-x: hidden" doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, overflow

This is my HTML ->

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UFT-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a CSS that is being imported by a JavaScript file, where I have placed the following lines:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

I don't know why, but it doesn't care about the hidden overflow on mobile. I have tried to do

```
body, html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

But then, I get a double vertical scrollbar where there should be just one.

Comment: `overflow-x` controls horizontal scrollbars. To control vertical scrollbars, you need to use `overflow-y`.

Comment: I know thanks. I think the problem has to do w/ this line -> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, eventually I tried adding this:

```
#root { 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It solved my problem, hope it does the same for you!

Comment: I'm not fully sure about what I did to solve the problem bc it was about 8 months ago... But I will tell you what I have as it may help you.

Comment: In the HTML I have the following line -> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Then, on CSS I added the following ->

Comment: * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

Comment: Also, I added some additional stuff to the Footer, Header as well as to all the Bodies. I guess it was a matter of adjusting everything perfectly. I wish I could remember which solution I came up with, but you're getting a bit late man... >_<